Why am I getting this computation error of unkown type name 'driver_proc'
Full screen of code and libraries
computation errors
I am encountering a compilation error related to driver_proc struct definition in my project for phase4. The error appears when I try to run make command and when list.h is trying to be compiled, the driver_proc is shown as unknown type name even though I defined it in driver.h and all of my .c files in my project. I attached a zip of my project and I was wondering if you had any suggestions. I've tried debugging and correcting the code but I cant seem to resolve it.
I keep trying to run make command to compile code but I keep getting errors in my list.h file stating:
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include "/mnt/d/Dev/usloss-dev/phase4/driver.h"

// Define the structure for a doubly linked list node
typedef struct Node {
    struct Node* next;  // Pointer to the next node
    struct Node* prev;  // Pointer to the previous node
    driver_proc* data;  // Pointer to data stored in the node, specifically driver_proc
} Node;

// Define the structure for the list itself
typedef struct List {
    Node* head;  // Pointer to the head (first node) of the list
    Node* tail;  // Pointer to the tail (last node) of the list
    int size;    // Integer to keep track of the list's size for quick access
} List;

// Function declarations for managing the list
void initList(List* list);                      // Initialize a new list
void addToList(List* list, driver_proc* item);  // Add an item to the list
driver_proc* removeFromList(List* list);        // Remove an item from the list and return it
int isListEmpty(const List* list);              // Check if the list is empty

#endif // LIST_H


heres my makefile
TARGET=libphase4.a
ASSIGNMENT=452phase4
CC=gcc
AR=ar
COBJS= phase4.o libuser.o p1.o 
CSRCS=${COBJS:.o=.c}
HDRS= server.h
INCLUDE = ./usloss/include
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -I${INCLUDE} -I. -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast

LDFLAGS = -L. -L./usloss/lib
TESTDIR=testcases

TESTS= test00 test01 test02 test03 test04 test05 test06 test07 test08 \
       test09 test10 test11 test12 

LIBS = -l452phase3 -l452phase2 -l452phase1 -lusloss \
       -l452phase1 -l452phase2 -l452phase3 -lphase4 


$(TARGET):  $(COBJS)
        $(AR) -r $@ $(COBJS) 

$(TESTS):   $(TARGET)  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(TESTDIR)/$@.c
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $@.o $(LIBS) 

clean:
    rm -f $(COBJS) $(TARGET) test*.o term*.out p1.o $(TESTS) core


phase4.o libuser.o p1.o: driver.h list.h


# Remove the definitions for startup and finish from phase1.o
# or ensure that only one of them is linked into the final library

# Add the definition for removeFromList to phase4.o or link the library containing it


Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the full and complete build log as text. And please try to create a [mre], with emphasis on the minimal bit.

But as an educated guess you likely have a circular include dependency. Your list.h file includes driver.h, but driver.h also includes list.h. The common way to deal with such problems is through forward declarations, and removing #include directives.

i removed #include "/mnt/d/Dev/usloss-dev/phase4/driver.h"
from list.h and make command worked. thx!
